# Maven archetypes for hibernate using JPA annotations method

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, maven-archetype

Does anyone know where to find or how to setup a hibernate project from a maven archetype? The important part being it using the standard JPA annotations method rather than the hibernate specific method with defining xml mapping files for your entity classes...

Comment: Not really much to it I see though, 2 dependencies namely 'hibernate-core' and 'hibernate-entitymanager' and creating a 'persistence.xml' under WEB-INF/

Answer (score 7):

I was working yesterday in a configuration for this and found useful the archetype `standalone-jpa-eclipselink-archetype` Use the `mvn archetype:generate` and select that artifact.

After running the command and create the project structure in interactive mode, then update your pom.xml with this, and delete the unused classes and configs for derby, unless you want to use derby.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpaMap</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.20</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

With that you will be able to use JPA annotations and have the correct structure in your project, don't forget to update the persistence.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />     
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```